# Powerbuild 12.1 datawindow Saveas with limited file types option

Tags: save-as, datawindow

I am using PB 12.1 Classic on Window 7.
When we use datawindow's saveas(), it either displays all files type or one specific file type based on saveastype argument. We need to display only certain filetypes e.g. CSV, Text, Excel, HTML and PSReport. I couldn't find saveas() with array argument for saveastype.
Does anyone know if we can filter choices for saveastype argument?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a PBNI extension that allows you to customize the standard dialog, including removing options you didn't want to display:

http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/80834